# Fastest method to search an array for matching color in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap

I am using GetPixel from a bitmap (using LockBits so no efficiency issue there) and need to search an array of colors for the location of the color within the array as fast as possible. I have very large bitmaps to iterate through.

```
...                
prevColor = Color.FromArgb(255, r, g, b);

int count = 1536;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
   if (prevColor == theColorScale[i])
   {
       loc = i;
       break;
   }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you keep your colors in an array and not a hashmap or dictionary?

Comment: To extend Renans Answer: I would recommend a HybridDictonary, which starts a a dictionay an changes to a Hashtable when it becomes larger (for performance). Please notice that a Hashmap not exists in c# (its java i think)

Comment: But OP is asking for position and HashSet is unordered

Comment: @Blam which smells like poor design. If you want to use an indexed structure to make operations on colors, you probably don't know how to work with color spaces and should rethink what you're doing.

Comment: The color array is an array of interpolated colors if that helps. Red > Yellow > Green > Blue > Purple

Comment: @Renan The stated question is position.

Comment: @QuestionMike we understood the question, and we can discourse all day long about the performance of linear searching... I just feel the urge to suggest that you review what you are doing. **Why** do you need that array? You could think of a color as a vector in a 4-dimensional space, or a 3-dimensional one if you drop the alpha channel. It's position is known by its four (or three) components. So you don't even need to search for its position in color space if you know what color it is.

Comment: @QuestionMike also notice that if all you want is to **identify** the color - that is, you are not going to do any mathematical operation at all with that index - then you can disregard my previous comment, and a dictionary will be the most performatic structure you can use.

Answer (score 1):

Accepting the question as stated

A Dictionary has O(1) lookup

```
Dictionary<color, Int32> colors = new Dictionary<color, Int32>();
...
loc = colors[prevColor];
```

The key (color) in the Dictionary must be unique

Comment: I am supposing that the OP is not going to make any complicated operation on the color, so this is basically what I'd answer too. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a List and search it using .IndexOf()?

```
...
List<Color> colorScale;
/* add colors */
loc = colorScale.IndexOf(prevColor);
```

Comment: Question is `Fastest method` this is O(n)

Comment: You know, I'm not downvoting this, but being pretty pedantic, that's far from the most performatic way to search for what you want.

Comment: They want fast, but it's already inefficient in the fact they want the index. It would have to be basically redone from the beginning to get fastest IMO. I'm not sure how the rest of their code is set up, so I just gave my 2 cents for a faster method to get the index (for whatever reason they need it for) *edit: Now that I look at it more, I'm assuming it's for a homework assignment if they are insisting on index. If they don't mind changing it, then there are faster ways

Comment: As I said, I'm just being pedantic. IndexOf will not be faster than unwinding the loop that the OP is already doing. This is specially feasible since his array is of fixed size, as he said in his comments.

Comment: Well TIL, I did not know that the efficiency was O(n) btw.

Comment: Unwinding is also O(n). It's still arguably faster. Though, really, we're talking about saving a few picosseconds every century here.

Comment: I absolutely need those picoseconds

Comment: Actually I just shot myself in the foot. A full unwind may reach O(1).